# Problem with javascript (jQuery). Works in firefox but not in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I have a problem with a site I am working on, available [here](http://dev.istocat.se/).

The javascript on the site works as inteded when browsed with firefox. In IE7, however, the javascript does not even get executed.

As I am new to javascript I suspect that I am probably doing an obvious mistake somewhere in the code.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You really need to provide bit more info here... for what it's worth, yes, jQuery does (and should) work on modern IE versions.
If you see any javascript problems notes by IE (alas, IE js debug support sucks), try to check those first.

Comment: IE js debug support does suck as much as most people think see:
http://notetodogself.blogspot.com/2008/08/debug-javascript-in-ie.html

The problem is that its MUCH harder to get working than downloading firebug in 15 seconds

Answer (score 9, accepted):

here is your problem:

```
$.get("ajax.php", {case: caseNr, picturenr: picNr, pictureinfo: true}, function(data){
```

**case** is a reserved word. When using hashes, always make keys be strings, and you will never get yourself in to  trouble

```
$.get("ajax.php", {"case": caseNr, "picturenr": picNr, "pictureinfo": true}, function(data){
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is on line 43, karlsten.js, on IE8, so you may want to debug it on IE8, if possible, or get the Web Developer Tools.
$.get("ajax.php", {case: caseNr,

But, someone just submitted this before I did, with a good answer. :)